# Silverlight. Save dynamic data to oob while it's installation

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-oob

I Have Silverlight out of browser app. And I need to save custom data from browser to oob application while it's installation.

In browser i'm getting data like this:

```
Request.QueryString["login"];
```

And I need to get access to that data from my oob app like this:

```
var login = GetLogin();
```

Maybe it could be saved to xml file or whatever...

Thanx for helping me.